# UITablViewCell dealing with changing the size of the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, bounds

Iam creating a custom UITableViewCell programatically , I need the height of the cell (which I changed) , at my custom cell I get the cell's height by self.contentView.bounds.height , which gives me the original height (not the changed one ) , how can I get the changed height ???

Comment: How and where did you change the height?

Comment: Are you changing the cell's height programmatically or are you using a xib/storyboard?

Comment: I changed it by heightForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1):

You MUST calculate cell height in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Otherwise tableView uses `Row Height` from Interface Builder `Size inspector` for tableView.

Comment: I didn't ask for the tableView , please read my question again :d

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
CGRect frame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//To get the height
NSLog(@"row height: %@", frame.size.height");
```

Comment: I want to do this from the the custom cell class